# how to pass path from excel cell to vb code?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I pass path from excel cell to vb code, so it will pick files from there for processing?

I am using below code where I am specifying the path explicitly. Instead I need to take it from excel cell.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please remove the picture of the code and rather copy the VBA code itself into your post.

Comment: Hi Kavya, it would be better if you pasted your code as text... and detail the search you did before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Update your variable declaration to show that `MyPath`  is a string:
`Dim MyPath as String` (this bit isn't essential, but it's good practice).

Next you just point it to a cell:  `MyPath = myWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`